# Is starting from sides a bad style?

Tags: opening, style

I am just an average chess player around 1500+ ELO
and have started experimenting to come up with a complete new style of my own. (it may have been used or discredited in the community)

This involves starting from corner pawns on each sides rather than the middle.

Here is an example game:-

```
[FEN ""]

1. h4 e5 2. h5 d5 3. a4 Nc6 4. e3 d4
5. g4 dxe3 6. fxe3 h6 7. Nc3 Nf6 8. Bg2 Bxg4
9. Bf3 Bxf3 10. Qxf3 Qd6 11. Nb5 Qd7 12. c3 a6
13. Na3 Bxa3 14. bxa3 O-O 15. d4 exd4 16. cxd4 Rae8
17. Ne2
```

What do you have say about this? What kind of chess player am I?

Comment: I'd say that you're the kind of player who has not yet understood the value of development and king safety. In the final position of the game excerpt white is in serious danger of losing due to issues with king safety.

Comment: I would also like to add that in the final position, despite the material difference being just a pawn you are in fact lost on Nxd4. Stockfish 9 evaluates the position as -6.4, which is as if you were more than a rook down. Your king is too exposed and you can't face all threats

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say you are wasting your own time. Black could have built a d5-e5 center with two bishops on d6 and e6 in your setup. Even in you own line, Black has all the winning chances due to weaker White king.

You are giving Black the development for free. Your opening idea won’t work against any decent player.

Please study normal openings.